# How do I know what .ebextensions config file to create?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I think I'm on the right path. I can use .ebextensions to change some of the conf files for the instance I'm running. Since I'm using Elastic Beanstalk, and that a lot of the software is shrinkwrapped (which I'm fine with), I should be using .ebextensions as a means of modifying the environment.

I want to employ some form of mod_rewrite config, but I know nothing of this Amazon Linux. I don't even know what the web server is. I've been through the console for the past few hours and see no trace of the things I want to override.

Apparently I can setup a shell to take a look around, but modifying things that way will cause things to be overridden since Beanstalk is handling config. I'm not entirely sure on that last point.

Should I just ssh and play in userland like a typical unix host?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can definitely ssh to the instance, and see around. But remember, that your changes are not persistent. You should look at .ebextensions config files as the way to re-run your commands on the host, plus more.

It might take some time to see where ElasticBeanstalk stores configuration files and all other interesting things.

To get you started, your app files are located at: `/opt/python/current/app` and if you are using Python, it is located in virtual environment at: `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python27`

[Customizing the Software on EC2 Instances Running Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) guide contains detailed information on what you can do:

- Packages - *install packages*
- Sources - *retrieve archives*
- Files - *operations with files*
- Users - *anything with users*
- Groups - *anything with groups*
- Commands - *execute instance commands*
- Container_commands - *execute commands after the container is
  extracted*
- Services - *launch services*
- Option_settings - *configure
  container settings*

See if that satisfies your requirements, if not, come back to StackOverflow and ask more questions.

Comment: I gotta say that your hints on where to find my app files and configuration were more succinct than anything I saw on the AWS doc pages. I'm running a ruby instance and I want to rewrite some urls. There is not httpd or conf.d directories (which are referenced in other howtos). Any further tips?

Comment: How about `/etc/httpd/conf.d`? I have it on my instance.

Comment: I do not have either of the folders anywhere on my instance.

Comment: @jacobsd Ah, it might be because Ruby containers are using Phusion Passenger (with nginx under the hood). [Deploying Ruby Applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Git](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git)

Comment: I'll post a new question related to that. Thanks Andrey

Comment: @jacobsd Try rebuilding your environment and then skim through the logs in Elastic Beanstalk console, I'm sure the logs will have plenty of information on how the environment is set up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45224/discussion-between-jacobsd-and-andrey-myatlyuk)